# Hostapd Wifi 6 channel not enabled though shown in iw list in Germany using Debian bookworm

Tags: debian, wifi, hostapd

I am trying to set up a Wifi 6 Access point with an Intel AX210 card on Debian Bookworm.

My configuration of the hostapd.conf file looks like:

```
interface=wlp2s0
bridge=br0
driver=nl80211
hw_mode=a
channel=93
ieee80211d=1
ieee80211ac=1
wmm_enabled=1
country_code=DE
ieee80211d=1
ieee80211h=1
basic_rates=60 120 240
ieee80211ax=1
ieee80211n=1
rts_threshold=-1
fragm_threshold=-1
beacon_int=100
dtim_period=2
max_num_sta=255
ssid=WLAN-RF001
auth_algs=3
eap_server=1
ieee8021x=1
eapol_version=2
wpa=2
wpa_key_mgmt=WPA-EAP
rsn_pairwise=CCMP
wpa_pairwise=TKIP
eap_user_file=/etc/hostapd/hostapd.eap_user
ca_cert=/etc/hostapd/ssl/cacert.pem
server_cert=/etc/hostapd/ssl/hostapd.pem
private_key=/etc/hostapd/ssl/hostapd.key
dh_file=/etc/hostapd/ssl

logger_syslog=-1
logger_syslog_level=1
logger_stdout=-1
logger_stdout_level=1

ctrl_interface=/var/run/hostapd
ctrl_interface_group=0
```

The channel 93 seems to be enabled now as per `iw list`:

```
[..]
    Band 4:
        HE Iftypes: managed
            HE MAC Capabilities (0x78018a30abc0):
                +HTC HE Supported
                Trigger Frame MAC Padding Duration: 2
                Multi-TID Aggregation Support: 7
                Broadcast TWT
                32-bit BA Bitmap
                OM Control
                Maximum A-MPDU Length Exponent: 1
                RX Control Frame to MultiBSS
                A-MSDU in A-MPDU
                Multi-TID Aggregation TX: 7
                UL 2x996-Tone RU
            HE PHY Capabilities: (0x0c3f0e09fd098c160ffc01):
                HE40/HE80/5GHz
                HE160/5GHz
                Punctured Preamble RX: 15
                Device Class: 1
                LDPC Coding in Payload
                NDP with 4x HE-LTF and 3.2us GI
                STBC Tx <= 80MHz
                STBC Rx <= 80MHz
                DCM Max Constellation: 1
                DCM Max Constellation Rx: 1
                SU Beamformee
                Beamformee STS <= 80Mhz: 7
                Beamformee STS > 80Mhz: 7
                Sounding Dimensions <= 80Mhz: 1
                Sounding Dimensions > 80Mhz: 1
                Triggered SU Beamforming Feedback
                Triggered MU Beamforming Feedback
                PPE Threshold Present
                Power Boost Factor ar
                HE SU PPDU & HE PPDU 4x HE-LTF 0.8us GI
                Max NC: 2
                HE ER SU PPDU 4x HE-LTF 0.8us GI
                20MHz in 40MHz HE PPDU 2.4GHz
                20MHz in 160/80+80MHz HE PPDU
                80MHz in 160/80+80MHz HE PPDU
                TX 1024-QAM
                RX 1024-QAM
                RX Full BW SU Using HE MU PPDU with Compression SIGB
                RX Full BW SU Using HE MU PPDU with Non-Compression SIGB
            HE RX MCS and NSS set <= 80 MHz
                1 streams: MCS 0-11
                2 streams: MCS 0-11
                3 streams: not supported
                4 streams: not supported
                5 streams: not supported
                6 streams: not supported
                7 streams: not supported
                8 streams: not supported
            HE TX MCS and NSS set <= 80 MHz
                1 streams: MCS 0-11
                2 streams: MCS 0-11
                3 streams: not supported
                4 streams: not supported
                5 streams: not supported
                6 streams: not supported
                7 streams: not supported
                8 streams: not supported
            HE RX MCS and NSS set 160 MHz
                1 streams: MCS 0-11
                2 streams: MCS 0-11
                3 streams: not supported
                4 streams: not supported
                5 streams: not supported
                6 streams: not supported
                7 streams: not supported
                8 streams: not supported
            HE TX MCS and NSS set 160 MHz
                1 streams: MCS 0-11
                2 streams: MCS 0-11
                3 streams: not supported
                4 streams: not supported
                5 streams: not supported
                6 streams: not supported
                7 streams: not supported
                8 streams: not supported
            PPE Threshold 0x61 0x1c 0xc7 0x71
        EHT Iftypes: managed
            EHT MAC Capabilities (0x0000):
            EHT PHY Capabilities: (0x0000000000000000):
            EHT MCS/NSS: (0x):
            EHT bw <= 80 MHz, max NSS for MCS 8-9: Rx=0, Tx=0
            EHT bw <= 80 MHz, max NSS for MCS 10-11: Rx=0, Tx=0
            EHT bw <= 80 MHz, max NSS for MCS 12-13: Rx=0, Tx=0
            EHT bw=160 MHz, max NSS for MCS 8-9: Rx=0, Tx=0
            EHT bw=160 MHz, max NSS for MCS 10-11: Rx=0, Tx=0
            EHT bw=160 MHz, max NSS for MCS 12-13: Rx=0, Tx=0
        HE Iftypes: AP
            HE MAC Capabilities (0x78010a100000):
                +HTC HE Supported
                Trigger Frame MAC Padding Duration: 2
                Multi-TID Aggregation Support: 7
                Broadcast TWT
                OM Control
                Maximum A-MPDU Length Exponent: 1
            HE PHY Capabilities: (0x04200e090009800401c400):
                HE40/HE80/5GHz
                LDPC Coding in Payload
                NDP with 4x HE-LTF and 3.2us GI
                STBC Tx <= 80MHz
                STBC Rx <= 80MHz
                DCM Max Constellation: 1
                DCM Max Constellation Rx: 1
                Sounding Dimensions <= 80Mhz: 1
                Sounding Dimensions > 80Mhz: 1
                PPE Threshold Present
                HE SU PPDU & HE PPDU 4x HE-LTF 0.8us GI
                HE ER SU PPDU 4x HE-LTF 0.8us GI
                TX 1024-QAM
            HE RX MCS and NSS set <= 80 MHz
                1 streams: MCS 0-11
                2 streams: MCS 0-11
                3 streams: not supported
                4 streams: not supported
                5 streams: not supported
                6 streams: not supported
                7 streams: not supported
                8 streams: not supported
            HE TX MCS and NSS set <= 80 MHz
                1 streams: MCS 0-11
                2 streams: MCS 0-11
                3 streams: not supported
                4 streams: not supported
                5 streams: not supported
                6 streams: not supported
                7 streams: not supported
                8 streams: not supported
            PPE Threshold 0x61 0x1c 0xc7 0x71
        EHT Iftypes: AP
            EHT MAC Capabilities (0x0000):
            EHT PHY Capabilities: (0x0000000000000000):
            EHT MCS/NSS: (0x):
            EHT bw <= 80 MHz, max NSS for MCS 8-9: Rx=0, Tx=0
            EHT bw <= 80 MHz, max NSS for MCS 10-11: Rx=0, Tx=0
            EHT bw <= 80 MHz, max NSS for MCS 12-13: Rx=0, Tx=0
        Bitrates (non-HT):
            * 6.0 Mbps
            * 9.0 Mbps
            * 12.0 Mbps
            * 18.0 Mbps
            * 24.0 Mbps
            * 36.0 Mbps
            * 48.0 Mbps
            * 54.0 Mbps
        Frequencies:
            * 5955 MHz [1] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5975 MHz [5] (22.0 dBm)
            * 5995 MHz [9] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6015 MHz [13] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6035 MHz [17] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6055 MHz [21] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6075 MHz [25] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6095 MHz [29] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6115 MHz [33] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6135 MHz [37] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6155 MHz [41] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6175 MHz [45] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6195 MHz [49] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6215 MHz [53] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6235 MHz [57] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6255 MHz [61] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6275 MHz [65] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6295 MHz [69] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6315 MHz [73] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6335 MHz [77] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6355 MHz [81] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6375 MHz [85] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6395 MHz [89] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6415 MHz [93] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6435 MHz [97] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6455 MHz [101] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6475 MHz [105] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6495 MHz [109] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6515 MHz [113] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6535 MHz [117] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6555 MHz [121] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6575 MHz [125] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6595 MHz [129] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6615 MHz [133] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6635 MHz [137] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6655 MHz [141] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6675 MHz [145] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6695 MHz [149] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6715 MHz [153] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6735 MHz [157] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6755 MHz [161] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6775 MHz [165] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6795 MHz [169] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6815 MHz [173] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6835 MHz [177] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6855 MHz [181] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6875 MHz [185] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6895 MHz [189] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6915 MHz [193] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6935 MHz [197] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6955 MHz [201] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6975 MHz [205] (22.0 dBm)
            * 6995 MHz [209] (22.0 dBm)
            * 7015 MHz [213] (22.0 dBm)
            * 7035 MHz [217] (22.0 dBm)
            * 7055 MHz [221] (22.0 dBm)
            * 7075 MHz [225] (22.0 dBm)
            * 7095 MHz [229] (22.0 dBm)
            * 7115 MHz [233] (22.0 dBm)
    Supported commands:
         * new_interface
         * set_interface
         * new_key
         * start_ap
         * new_station
         * new_mpath
         * set_mesh_config
         * set_bss
         * authenticate
         * associate
         * deauthenticate
         * disassociate
         * join_ibss
         * join_mesh
         * remain_on_channel
         * set_tx_bitrate_mask
         * frame
         * frame_wait_cancel
         * set_wiphy_netns
         * set_channel
         * tdls_mgmt
         * tdls_oper
         * start_sched_scan
         * probe_client
         * set_noack_map
         * register_beacons
         * start_p2p_device
         * set_mcast_rate
         * connect
         * disconnect
         * channel_switch
         * set_qos_map
         * add_tx_ts
         * set_multicast_to_unicast
    WoWLAN support:
         * wake up on disconnect
         * wake up on magic packet
         * wake up on pattern match, up to 20 patterns of 16-128 bytes,
           maximum packet offset 0 bytes
         * can do GTK rekeying
         * wake up on GTK rekey failure
         * wake up on EAP identity request
         * wake up on 4-way handshake
         * wake up on rfkill release
         * wake up on network detection, up to 8 match sets
    software interface modes (can always be added):
         * AP/VLAN
         * monitor
    valid interface combinations:
         * #{ managed } <= 1, #{ AP, P2P-client, P2P-GO } <= 1, #{ P2P-device } <= 1,
           total <= 3, #channels <= 2
    HT Capability overrides:
         * MCS: ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff ff
         * maximum A-MSDU length
         * supported channel width
         * short GI for 40 MHz
         * max A-MPDU length exponent
         * min MPDU start spacing
    Device supports TX status socket option.
    Device supports HT-IBSS.
    Device supports SAE with AUTHENTICATE command
    Device supports low priority scan.
    Device supports scan flush.
    Device supports per-vif TX power setting
    P2P GO supports CT window setting
    P2P GO supports opportunistic powersave setting
    Driver supports full state transitions for AP/GO clients
    Driver supports a userspace MPM
    Driver/device bandwidth changes during BSS lifetime (AP/GO mode)
    Device adds DS IE to probe requests
    Device can update TPC Report IE
    Device supports static SMPS
    Device supports dynamic SMPS
    Device supports WMM-AC admission (TSPECs)
    Device supports configuring vdev MAC-addr on create.
    Device supports randomizing MAC-addr in scans.
    Device supports randomizing MAC-addr in sched scans.
    Device supports randomizing MAC-addr in net-detect scans.
    max # scan plans: 2
    max scan plan interval: 65535
    max scan plan iterations: 254
    Supported TX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * managed: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * mesh point: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-client: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
         * P2P-device: 0x00 0x10 0x20 0x30 0x40 0x50 0x60 0x70 0x80 0x90 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0 0xe0 0xf0
    Supported RX frame types:
         * IBSS: 0x40 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * managed: 0x40 0xb0 0xd0
         * AP: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * AP/VLAN: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * mesh point: 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-client: 0x40 0xd0
         * P2P-GO: 0x00 0x20 0x40 0xa0 0xb0 0xc0 0xd0
         * P2P-device: 0x40 0xd0
    Supported extended features:
        * [ VHT_IBSS ]: VHT-IBSS
        * [ RRM ]: RRM
        * [ MU_MIMO_AIR_SNIFFER ]: MU-MIMO sniffer
        * [ SCAN_START_TIME ]: scan start timestamp
        * [ BSS_PARENT_TSF ]: BSS last beacon/probe TSF
        * [ BEACON_RATE_LEGACY ]: legacy beacon rate setting
        * [ FILS_STA ]: STA FILS (Fast Initial Link Setup)
        * [ FILS_MAX_CHANNEL_TIME ]: FILS max channel attribute override with dwell time
        * [ ACCEPT_BCAST_PROBE_RESP ]: accepts broadcast probe response
        * [ OCE_PROBE_REQ_HIGH_TX_RATE ]: probe request TX at high rate (at least 5.5Mbps)
        * [ CONTROL_PORT_OVER_NL80211 ]: control port over nl80211
        * [ TXQS ]: FQ-CoDel-enabled intermediate TXQs
        * [ ENABLE_FTM_RESPONDER ]: enable FTM (Fine Time Measurement) responder
        * [ CONTROL_PORT_NO_PREAUTH ]: disable pre-auth over nl80211 control port support
        * [ PROTECTED_TWT ]: protected Target Wake Time (TWT) support
        * [ DEL_IBSS_STA ]: deletion of IBSS station support
        * [ BEACON_PROTECTION_CLIENT ]: beacon prot. for clients support
        * [ SCAN_FREQ_KHZ ]: scan on kHz frequency support
        * [ CONTROL_PORT_OVER_NL80211_TX_STATUS ]: tx status for nl80211 control port support
```

I am using the iwlwifi firmware directly from git.kernel.org (cloned and checkout out today).

I have googled the web, and they say it should be working now to set up a Wifi 6 AP with an AX210 card with a most recent firmware and kernel. I am using kernel 6.3.

But when I start hostapd, I get the following error message:

```
# hostapd -dd /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
random: getrandom() support available
Configuration file: /etc/hostapd/hostapd.conf
eapol_version=2
ctrl_interface_group=0
nl80211: TDLS supported
nl80211: TDLS external setup
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:1
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:5
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:2
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:4
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:8
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:9
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:6
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:11
nl80211: Supported cipher 00-0f-ac:12
nl80211: Using driver-based off-channel TX
nl80211: Driver-advertised extended capabilities (default) - hexdump(len=8): 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 40
nl80211: Driver-advertised extended capabilities mask (default) - hexdump(len=8): 04 00 00 00 00 00 00 40
nl80211: Driver-advertised extended capabilities for interface type STATION
nl80211: Extended capabilities - hexdump(len=8): 04 00 40 00 00 00 00 40
nl80211: Extended capabilities mask - hexdump(len=8): 04 00 40 00 00 00 00 40
nl80211: Use separate P2P group interface (driver advertised support)
nl80211: Enable multi-channel concurrent (driver advertised support)
nl80211: use P2P_DEVICE support
nl80211: key_mgmt=0x1ff0f enc=0x76f auth=0x7 flags=0x5800d30fb5bfbe0 rrm_flags=0x19 probe_resp_offloads=0x0 max_stations=0 max_remain_on_chan=10000 max_scan_ssids=20
nl80211: interface wlp2s0 in phy phy1
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 24 iftype 3 (AP)
nl80211: Setup AP(wlp2s0) - device_ap_sme=0 use_monitor=0
nl80211: Subscribe to mgmt frames with AP handle 0x557920775260
nl80211: Register frame type=0xb0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_AUTH) nl_handle=0x557920775260 match= multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0x0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ASSOC_REQ) nl_handle=0x557920775260 match= multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0x20 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_REASSOC_REQ) nl_handle=0x557920775260 match= multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xa0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_DISASSOC) nl_handle=0x557920775260 match= multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xc0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_DEAUTH) nl_handle=0x557920775260 match= multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0x40 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_PROBE_REQ) nl_handle=0x557920775260 match= multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557920775260 match=04 multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557920775260 match=0501 multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557920775260 match=0503 multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557920775260 match=0504 multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557920775260 match=06 multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557920775260 match=08 multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557920775260 match=09 multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557920775260 match=0a multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557920775260 match=11 multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557920775260 match=12 multicast=0
nl80211: Register frame type=0xd0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_ACTION) nl_handle=0x557920775260 match=7f multicast=0
rfkill: initial event: idx=1 type=1 op=0 soft=0 hard=0
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 6 (ifidx_reason 24)
nl80211: if_indices[16]: 6(24)
nl80211: Add own interface ifindex 24 (ifidx_reason -1)
nl80211: if_indices[16]: 6(24) 24(-1)
nl80211: Adding interface wlp2s0 into bridge br0
nl80211: Do not open EAPOL RX socket - using control port for RX
phy: phy1
BSS count 1, BSSID mask 00:00:00:00:00:00 (0 bits)
wlp2s0: interface state UNINITIALIZED->COUNTRY_UPDATE
Previous country code DE, new country code DE
nl80211: No channel number found for frequency 5905 MHz
nl80211: Regulatory information - country=00
nl80211: 2402-2437 @ 40 MHz 22 mBm
nl80211: 2422-2462 @ 40 MHz 22 mBm
nl80211: 2447-2482 @ 40 MHz 22 mBm
nl80211: 5170-5190 @ 160 MHz 22 mBm (no outdoor) (no IR)
nl80211: 5190-5210 @ 160 MHz 22 mBm (no outdoor) (no IR)
nl80211: 5210-5230 @ 160 MHz 22 mBm (no outdoor) (no IR)
nl80211: 5230-5250 @ 160 MHz 22 mBm (no outdoor) (no IR)
nl80211: 5250-5270 @ 160 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5270-5290 @ 160 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5290-5310 @ 160 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5310-5330 @ 160 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5490-5510 @ 240 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5510-5530 @ 240 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5530-5550 @ 240 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5550-5570 @ 240 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5570-5590 @ 240 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5590-5610 @ 240 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5610-5630 @ 240 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5630-5650 @ 240 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5650-5670 @ 80 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5670-5690 @ 80 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5690-5710 @ 80 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5710-5730 @ 80 MHz 22 mBm (DFS) (no IR)
nl80211: 5735-5755 @ 80 MHz 22 mBm (no IR)
nl80211: 5755-5775 @ 80 MHz 22 mBm (no IR)
nl80211: 5775-5795 @ 80 MHz 22 mBm (no IR)
nl80211: 5795-5815 @ 80 MHz 22 mBm (no IR)
nl80211: 5815-5835 @ 40 MHz 22 mBm (no IR)
nl80211: Added 802.11b mode based on 802.11g information
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11g: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 2484[DISABLED]
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11a: 5180[NO_IR] 5200[NO_IR] 5220[NO_IR] 5240[NO_IR] 5260[NO_IR][RADAR] 5280[NO_IR][RADAR] 5300[NO_IR][RADAR] 5320[NO_IR][RADAR] 5340[DISABLED] 5360[DISABLED] 5380[DISABLED] 5400[DISABLED] 5420[DISABLED]
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11a: 5955[DISABLED] 5975[DISABLED] 5995[DISABLED] 6015[DISABLED] 6035[DISABLED] 6055[DISABLED] 6075[DISABLED] 6095[DISABLED] 6115[DISABLED] 6135[DISABLED] 6155[DISABLED] 6175[DISABLED] 6195[DISABLED]
nl80211: Mode IEEE 802.11b: 2412 2417 2422 2427 2432 2437 2442 2447 2452 2457 2462 2467 2472 2484[DISABLED]
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=12 freq=2467 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=1 chan=13 freq=2472 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=52 freq=5260 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm (DFS state = usable)
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=56 freq=5280 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm (DFS state = usable)
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=60 freq=5300 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm (DFS state = usable)
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=64 freq=5320 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm (DFS state = usable)
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=100 freq=5500 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm (DFS state = usable)
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=104 freq=5520 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm (DFS state = usable)
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=108 freq=5540 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm (DFS state = usable)
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=112 freq=5560 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm (DFS state = usable)
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=116 freq=5580 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm (DFS state = usable)
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=120 freq=5600 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm (DFS state = usable)
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=124 freq=5620 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm (DFS state = usable)
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=128 freq=5640 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm (DFS state = usable)
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=132 freq=5660 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm (DFS state = usable)
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=136 freq=5680 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm (DFS state = usable)
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=140 freq=5700 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm (DFS state = usable)
Allowed channel: mode=2 chan=144 freq=5720 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm (DFS state = usable)
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=1 freq=2412 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=2 freq=2417 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=3 freq=2422 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=4 freq=2427 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=5 freq=2432 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=6 freq=2437 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=7 freq=2442 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=8 freq=2447 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=9 freq=2452 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=10 freq=2457 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=11 freq=2462 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=12 freq=2467 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Allowed channel: mode=0 chan=13 freq=2472 MHz max_tx_power=22 dBm
Could not determine operating frequency
wlp2s0: interface state COUNTRY_UPDATE->DISABLED
wlp2s0: AP-DISABLED
wlp2s0: Unable to setup interface.
hostapd_interface_deinit_free(0x5579207699e0)
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: num_bss=1 conf->num_bss=1
hostapd_interface_deinit(0x5579207699e0)
wlp2s0: interface state DISABLED->DISABLED
hostapd_bss_deinit: deinit bss wlp2s0
wlp2s0: Deauthenticate all stations
nl80211: send_mlme - da=ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff noack=0 freq=0 no_cck=0 offchanok=0 wait_time=0 no_encrypt=0 fc=0xc0 (WLAN_FC_STYPE_DEAUTH) nlmode=3
nl80211: send_mlme - Use bss->freq=0
nl80211: send_mlme -> send_frame_cmd
nl80211: CMD_FRAME freq=0 wait=0 no_cck=0 no_ack=0 offchanok=0
CMD_FRAME - hexdump(len=26): c0 00 00 00 ff ff ff ff ff ff 7c b5 66 c3 65 fe 7c b5 66 c3 65 fe 00 00 03 00
nl80211: Frame command failed: ret=-22 (Invalid argument) (freq=0 wait=0)
wlp2s0: AP-DISABLED
hostapd_cleanup(hapd=0x55792076b190 (wlp2s0))
wlp2s0: CTRL-EVENT-TERMINATING
hostapd_free_hapd_data: Interface wlp2s0 wasn't started
hostapd_interface_deinit_free: driver=0x55791fad4760 drv_priv=0x5579207700c0 -> hapd_deinit
nl80211: deinit ifname=wlp2s0 disabled_11b_rates=0
nl80211: Remove monitor interface: refcount=0
nl80211: Remove beacon (ifindex=24)
netlink: Operstate: ifindex=24 linkmode=0 (kernel-control), operstate=6 (IF_OPER_UP)
nl80211: Set mode ifindex 24 iftype 2 (STATION)
nl80211: Teardown AP(wlp2s0) - device_ap_sme=0 use_monitor=0
nl80211: Unsubscribe mgmt frames handle 0x8888ddf1a8ffdae9 (AP teardown)
hostapd_interface_free(0x5579207699e0)
hostapd_interface_free: free hapd 0x55792076b190
hostapd_cleanup_iface(0x5579207699e0)
hostapd_cleanup_iface_partial(0x5579207699e0)
hostapd_cleanup_iface: free iface=0x5579207699e0
```

Any ideas what could be wrong with my configuration?

After having started hostapd with this configuration, my 6 Ghz channels in `iw list` get disabled.

Comment: Channel 149 though in Germany works with the AX mode, but it's only 5Ghz and the real throughput is only about 800 Mbps.

Answer (score 1):

Did you check the regulatory database on your system?
You can verify it by running the command "iw reg get". Even if the channel is listed as supported by "iw list", the regulatory database might still prevent access point usage on it.

Comment: according to `iw reg get` I can see 6Ghz channels, but hostapd seems not to use them. Also, I can see that on `phy#0 (self-managed)`, DFS is set to DFS-UNSET. See yourself: https://pastebin.com/EYeXgeer

Comment: I am not sure but the channel 93 (center frequency 6414 MHz) you are using seems to be labeled as "PASSIVE-SCAN" only: "(6405 - 6425 @ 480), (6, 22), (N/A), NO-OUTDOOR, AUTO-BW, IR-CONCURRENT, NO-HT40MINUS, PASSIVE-SCAN".  So I guess this will prevent hostapd to run to this channel.   Did you test with other country codes that are not labelled as "PASSIVE_SCAN"?

Comment: Other country codes? Why other country codes? I used country code DE, as I am in Germany.
Also, all 6 Ghz channels are listed with PASSIVE_SCAN according to `iw reg get`. I have tried several of them, but all with no success.

Comment: I was just proposing you to use another country code as a quick test to check if the issue you are seeing is well related to the "PASSIVE-SCAN" flag you are seeing with "iw reg get". You could by example force it to US for a quick test (via "iw reg set US") and check if the 6GHz channel are allowed there. If hostapd is then working on the 6GHz then, it would confirm the issue comes from the "PASSIVE-SCAN" flag ...

Comment: It might, but it's not allowed to set to US in Germany, as possible US-frequencies might not be allowed in Germany. It doesn't help me anyway if it works with the US setting, as I can't set it permanently. I would like to understand why the channel gets disabled, once I start hostapd with it. That is pretty weird to me, I just guess the regulatory.db does not contain allowed 6Ghz frequencies for Germany yet, but I have read the contrary on the some commit on GitHub where these frequencies should have been enabled for Germany.

Comment: I found out now, that the Intel AX210 device has its own regulatory db on the chip (EPROM) and the iwlwifi firmware uses that regulatory db ("self-managed" mode). The iwlwifi firmware seems to ignore the regulatory db that comes with it. This is related to LAR, location aware regulatory, which was possible to disable on the Linux kernel driver with the lar_disable=1 parameter until Kernel version 5.3, but it seems not to work anymore.

Comment: Does anyone know how to bring the iwlwifi driver into user space managed mode? Or does anyone know a Wifi 6E card, that has a regulatory db that works in Germany in 6Ghz mode?